The order of product of two reflections in a Coxeter group
Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system. For any $s,t\in S$, denote $m_{st}$ be the order of $st$. By a reflection, we mean the element in $W$ which conjugates to some simple reflection.
My question is: Let $\sigma,\tau$ be two reflections. Does the order of $\sigma\tau$ always divide some $m_{st}$ with $s,t\in S$ and $m_{st}<\infty$, or equal to $\infty$?
Expecting your reply, thank you.

Yes: every finite reflection subgroup $W'$ with rank $r$ is a subgroup of a finite parabolic subgroup of rank $r$. So if $\sigma\tau$ has finite order, then $\langle \sigma,\tau\rangle$ is a reflection subgroup of the dihedral group of order $2m_{st}$ for some $s,t\in S$, so the order of $\sigma\tau$ divides $m_{st}$.

Thank you for your reply
